# Turn an IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> into an IEnumerable<IObservable<T>>

Tags: c#, linq, system.reactive

How would I turn an observable of an enumerable `xys` into an enumerable of observables `yxs`, where each observable of `yxs` focuses on a particular element of each time step of `xys`? What I want is similar to transposition for an enumerable of enumerables.

Example:

```
IObservable<IEnumerable<int>> xys = Observable.Generate(0, _ => true, i => ++i, i => new[] {0 + i, 1 + i, 2 + i});
// xys = emits {0,1,2}, {1,2,3}, ...
IEnumerable<IObservable<int>> yxs = new[]
{
    Observable.Generate(0, i=>true, i=> ++i, i=>i),
    Observable.Generate(1, i=>true, i=> ++i, i=>i),
    Observable.Generate(2, i=>true, i=> ++i, i=>i),
};
// yxs = {emits 0, 1, ...}, {emits 1, 2, ...}, {emits 2, 3, ...}
```

I'm specifically interested in a function which is already part of Rx. Like the above example, infinite observables should be possible as well as infinite enumerables.

Comment: You can't ever do this and produce meaningful results. The problem is that the inner `IEnumerable<T>` is unbounded in practice so any future value of the `IObservable<IEnumerable<int>>` may have more (or even infinite) values than a previous step yet the `IEnumerable<IObservable<T>>` would have to somehow know this ahead of time to product the correct number of enumerables. The best you can do is map a `IObservable<IEnumerable<int>>` to a `IObservable<IObservable<int>>`.

Comment: You are right that it doesn't work in general, but my answer below gets you as far as that you just have to `.Take()` as many observables as you need. The problem is equivalent to transposing an enumerable of enumerables, which of course isn't possible in general, too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I came up with so far. However, it's a self made solution, not part of Rx. I would appreciate far more if someone pointed me to a solution involving library functions.

```
public static IEnumerable<IObservable<T>> ObserveElements<T>(this IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> obs)
{
    var i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        var idx = i++;
        yield return from enumerable in obs
                     let x = enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault(idx)
                     where !Equals(x, default(T))
                     select x;
    }
}
```

Obviously, you would `.Take()` only as much observables as you need.

In Haskell terms, I think it's actually an implementation of `sequence` for the `IObservable` monad, specialized to `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 2):

This converts your "types" correctly. However, you can't change the semantics of when/how the elements are delivered underneath, so you're really just going to end up buffering and blocking no matter how you go about this.

```
dest = source.ToEnumerable().Map(x => x.ToObservable());
```

Comment: You probably meant `Select` instead of `Map`. This answers my question, but as you guessed it's unpractical for infinite observables. I'll edit my question.

Comment: I meant map. I don't adhere to .NET "standards" when there's perfectly good global standards based in mathematics out there. :) Also, there's an alias somewhere hidden in the .NET/Rx libraries out there somewhere.

Comment: I edited my answer. Pretty sure that should work for infinite sequences. Assuming you schedule things correctly.

Comment: Hmm... When I use it that way, I get a deadlock for my event stream which is probably caused by the non lazy implementation of `ToEnumerable()`. So yeah, if you schedule things correctly :)